# Work hours per week put in by senior management

Tags: management, work-life-balance

I want to get an idea of how many work hours a week does any senior executive put in, in a mid-size or large corporation, on a regular basis? Do they also have a 5 day work week? By senior management I mean people at positions like, VP,COO, or maybe a bit lower than those. I basically wanted to know if they have any work-life balance.

Comment: Not sure how anyone can answer this question the way it's worded. Each senior executive is a separate individual and you can't really lump them up and guess :P

Comment: Maybe so. But you could share what you've seen or experienced

Comment: From the [FAQ](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.*  If you have a concern or would like help addressing an issue we can probably provide you some direction.  But this question is not really useful or applicable to any real world problems.  One thing to consider is senior management is never really off.  They get calls at all hours about the business.

Comment: @Chad: Will keep that in mind.sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every individual is different.  I have worked at companies where having the upper level management in more than twice a week was considered incredible, and also (same company) another senior level management who built a custom gaming PC for his office, and spent all his time playing counter strike.

Then there are other places i've worked where the senior management was in every morning at 7, and left every night past 6.  There is no cookie-cutter answer for you.  It'll all depend on the individual in question's personal sense of responsibility and entitlement.  If they're of the "i'm more important than you because i own the company" mindset, you won't see them often.  But if they're of the "lead by example" or "it's up to me to make this place succeed, after all, i own the company" then seeing them all the time is to be expected.

Comment: Just because you do not see them in the office does not mean they are not working.  In larger companies high level execs tend to become a distraction with completing work when they are in the office.  Far to many people who are otherwise great managers work too hard trying to be noticed by the VP, CIO, CEO, etc.  So often working from a home office is best for the business.

Comment: @Chad while in principle i do agree, the examples i gave are 100% accurate.

Comment: I had known more "I'm more important that you" types that were there at the office showing us how important they were by getting in the way of us doing the job :p

Comment: @Chad in my experience, the in-office ones of that category tended to be the regular managers.  senior level, in the context i'm referring to are the VP's, the owners...the ones with parking spots basically.

Comment: I have worked at a few places where those senior types were aggressively involved in the micromanagement of the business.  I even had one owner who was hyper involved via fax machine and phone despite being 2500 miles away.  That was probably my worst experience since detassling as a 12 yo with 16yo's bossing us around.